# Prawn PDF and Action Mailer not attaching PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm using Prawn PDF and Actionmailer to send a pdf on completion of a sign up form, but it's just sending text rather then attaching the pdf. Not quite sure what i'm missing, but any help would be appriciated.

Example

```
--
Content-Type: application/pdf;
charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename=file.pdf

JVBERi0xLjQKJf////8KMSAwIG9iago8PCAvQ3JlYXRvciA8ZmVmZjAwNTAw
MDcyMDA2MTAwNzcwMDZlPgovUHJvZHVjZXIgPGZlZmYwMDUwMDA3MjAwNjEw...
```

PRAWN PDF

```
# encoding: utf-8
class FormPdf < Prawn::Document

  def initialize(form)
    super()
    @form = form
    all
  end

  def all
    text "Form text here"
    end
  end
```

Controller

```
def create
    @form = Form(params[:form])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @form.save
        FormMailer.send_form(@form).deliver
      else
      end
    end
  end
```

Mailer

```
class FormMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@random.com"

  def send_form(form)
    @g form = form
    pdf = FormPdf.new(@ form)
    attachments["file.pdf"] = { mime_type: 'application/pdf', content: pdf.render() }
    mail to: @form.email, subject: "Form"
  end
end
```

Comment: I have resolved this. Realised i didn't have a view template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this. Realised i didn't have a view template.